# How do I use django db API to save all the elements of a given column in a dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I've used a raw SQL Query to access them, and it seems to have worked.  However, I can't figure out a way to actually print the results to an array.  The only thing that I can find is  the cursor.fetchone() command, which gives me a single row.

Is there any way that I can return an entire column in a django query set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict(MyModel.objects.values_list('id', 'my_column'))` will return a dictionary with all elements of `my_column` with the row's id as the key. But probably you're just looking for a list of all the values, which you should receive via `MyModel.objects.values_list('my_column', flat=True)`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor.fetchall() instead of cursor.fetchone() to retrieve all rows.
And then extract nessesary field:

```
raw_items = cursor.fetchall()
items = [ item.field for item in raw_items ]
```